# Bash, switch columns in csv file, with quotation marks divided by `,`

Tags: bash, csv, awk, switch-statement

In bash, how can I switch 2 columns (2nd column switch as the last column) in csv, with quotation marks, divided by `,`?

**Input file**

```
...

232948,55,Titulka,"Vnitřní štuk, jemný 25 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg
232948,55,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg
232948,79,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg
232948,79,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg

...
```

**Expected output**

```
...

232948,Titulka,"Vnitřní štuk, jemný 25 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,55
232948,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,55
232948,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,79
232948,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,79

...
```

**I tried**

```
awk -F ',' ' { t = $2; $2 = $6; $6 = t; print; } ' OFS=',' "input-file.csv" > "output-file.csv"
```

It works, but for line with quotes, there is problem, it takes `,` inside `"` too.

How can I do it for array with `"`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure `awk` do not mess around with comma within field, use `FPAT` with `gnu awk`

```
awk -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" -v OFS=, '{$0=$0OFS$2;$2=f;sub(/,,/,",")}1' file
232948,Titulka,"Vnitřní štuk, jemný 25 kg",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,55
232948,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,55
232948,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,79
232948,Titulka,Vnitřní štuk jemný 25 kg,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/stavba-stavebni-materialy-sparovaci-hmoty-a-stuky-stuk-vnitrni-jemny-25kg/142812p/?utm_source=kupi&utm_medium=letak&utm_campaign=9_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/232948.jpg,79
```

- `FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"` this define how the field looks like, and not the Field Separators
- `$0=$0OFS$2;$2=f;sub(/,,/,",")` Move second field to end and remove second field.
- `1` just true, so do default action `print line`

Comment: Thanks, maybe I ask wrong. I need "move" 2nd column to end of line as last column, behind the last column, not switch for last column. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. And what if I want switch for example col2 and col4? Just want to understand second parameter. Thanks.

Comment: @genderbee To switch two column.  `{f=$2;$2=$4;$4=f}`